# dealing with numbers after float point

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am just stuck in this situation. Is there any way in SQL 
to get rid off from all numbers except two numbers after decimal point?
for example, lets say 125.36987 so as the output i want only 125.36.
Ive tried to multiply it to 100 then use cast it to int and divide by 100.0 
but still getting not what i want.

Answer (score 0):

use `ROUND()`

```
select round(125.36987, 2, 1)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11862)
- [ROUND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx)

Here's the detail. the syntax,

```
ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )
```

> **function**
>
> Is the type of operation to perform. function must be tinyint,
>   smallint, or int. When function is omitted or has a value of 0
>   (default), numeric_expression is rounded. When a value other than 0 is
>   specified, numeric_expression is truncated.

Answer (score 0):

YES,ROUND CAN SOLVE THAT.
SELECT ROUND(125.36987,2) FROM DUAL; YOU CAN GET 125.37
Or if YOU DON'T NEED round-off ， you can use 'trunc'
like this   TRUNC(125.36987,2)   125.36